# Displaying different data from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I want to display data from different columns into my html page.

```
<?php

require '../../config.php';

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Empresa WHERE id='3'";
$result = $connection->query($query); 
?>

<div class="col-md-6">
           <h3> <?php
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row["name"]; }
                ?> </h3>
            <br>
            <p><?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 echo $row["description"];}
                    ?></p>
        </div>
```

On the first instance it works fine no matter what column I call but after the first loop it never displays anything again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this, you can do with single loop :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<h3>".$row["nombre"]."</h3>";
            echo "<p>".$row["description"]."</p>";
        }
        result -> free();
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: ok that works! but what if i want to display more data outside this div? 
can i only get one loop to work?

Comment: More data means. If data is of the same row, then sure, you can initiate the loop outside of the `<div>`.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then you should mark it as the selected answer for this question. And you can while loop any were to get any amount of data for the selected table. If you want to call some thing from another table which is not in the selected on then you need to use `JOIN`.

Comment: @$errano Glad it help. Waiting for the green sign

Comment: Downwote for what ???

Comment: @Sand i have tried and only the first loop works. when i try and loop again in another div it doesnt get the data. idk why

Comment: I think you can fin the answer in the duplicate link.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What ? this is not my question I didn't mark anything.

Comment: @Serrano you shouldn't mark the answer that didn't help you. this is the rules violation.